# How can I shorten this SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to run this four times how can i do it in one line or may be less lines

```
update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
where oppar_job_name in ('ABC') ) and oppar_job_rec in ('ABC');

update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
where oppar_job_name in ('DEF') ) and oppar_job_rec in ('DEF');

update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
where oppar_job_name in ('FGH') ) and oppar_job_rec in ('FGH');

update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
where oppar_job_name in ('IJK') ) and oppar_job_rec in ('IJK');
```

I am thinking of trying this.

```
update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
where oppar_job_name in (
'ABC',
'DEF',
'FGH',
'IJK'
) and oppar_job_rec in 
(
'ABC',
'DEF',
'FGH',
'IJK'
);
```

Is the just above thing correct.
I mean there is a one to one correspondence in the table like

```
ABC ABC
DEF DEF
FGH FGH
IJK IJK
```

Comment: Your shortened SQL will also affect rows having ABC DEF, ABC FGH, ABC IJK,.. and so on

Comment: @KaipaMSarma no because he says there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between those two columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand well:

> ```
> update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0, 
> where (oppar_job_name = oppar_job_rec) and 
>       (oppar_job_rec in ('ABC','DEF','FGH','IJK'));
> ```

It's better with extra parenthesis ;-)

Comment: +1. smart work. I was looking for this. Btw are you smiling in the pic:)

Answer (score 1):

If there's a one-to-one correspondence between the columns, then your solution is correct (but has syntax errors) and unludo's solution is even better.

Otherwise you can make it more concise by avoiding multiple update statements like this:

```
update opp set 
    run_mode = 0, run_time = 0
where 
    (oppar_job_name in ('ABC') and oppar_job_rec in ('ABC')) OR
    (oppar_job_name in ('DEF') and oppar_job_rec in ('DEF')) OR
    (oppar_job_name in ('FGH') and oppar_job_rec in ('FGH')) OR
    (oppar_job_name in ('IJK') and oppar_job_rec in ('IJK'));
```

Finally you don't even need to use the `in` operator, so you can write something like this:

```
update opp set 
    run_mode = 0, run_time = 0
where 
    (oppar_job_name = 'ABC' and oppar_job_rec = 'ABC') OR
    (oppar_job_name = 'DEF' and oppar_job_rec = 'DEF') OR
    (oppar_job_name = 'FGH' and oppar_job_rec = 'FGH') OR
    (oppar_job_name = 'IJK' and oppar_job_rec = 'IJK');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your oppar_job_name and oppar_job_rec predicates are always identical, I prefer unludo's answer.

Otherwise, if the parameters might be different, you can do something like this:

```
update opp set run_mode = 0, run_time = 0
where ( oppar_job_name, oppar_job_rec )
in ( ('ABCname' , 'ABCrec')
   , ('DEFname' , 'DEFrec')
   , ('FGHname' , 'FGHrec')
   , ('IJKname' , 'IJKrec')
   );
```